# List Contents of Directory in a UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsarray, nsfilemanager

I am trying to list the contents of Ringtones directory in a TableView, however, I am only getting the last file in the directory in ALL cells, instead of file per cell. This is my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    Profile_ManagerAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        cell.hidesAccessoryWhenEditing = YES;
    }

    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    //cell.textLabel.text = @"No Ringtones";
    //cell.textLabel.text = @"Test";

    NSString *theFiles;
    NSFileManager *manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSArray *fileList = [manager directoryContentsAtPath:@"/Test"];
    for (NSString *s in fileList){
        theFiles = s;
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = theFiles;

    return cell;
}
```

It loads fine, no errors, when I use `NSLog` it lists all the files in the directory just fine. I even tried `[s objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]` but i get **objectAtIndex:** error. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: maybe you should create the arrays in the header so you can access the file anywhere in the main file. if you don't then how can you set the number of table items there are unless you already pre-set the number but if your having people add files or delete it would be easier to get the count of items in the directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your for loop is just iterating over the files and setting theFiles to the current path.  So at the end of the loop, theFiles will just be the last string in the collection.

Try something like:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [fileList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Comment: You are semi-correct on this answer, what was actually incorrect was the NSMutableArray wich allowed the objectAtIndex.

Comment: objectAtIndex is provided on NSArray though is it not?

Answer (score 1):

I actually love asking questions on here, cause in less than 10 minutes, I answer my own question!

This is how I got the above code to work:

```
NSMutableArray *theFiles;
NSFileManager *manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSArray *fileList = [manager directoryContentsAtPath:@"/Test"];
for (NSString *s in fileList){
    theFiles = fileList;
}
cell.textLabel.text = [theFiles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
return cell;
```

I just made the NSString an NSMutableArray, and that allowed me to use the objectAtIndex. Now to trim the file extension!

Comment: You do realise that you're copying the array several times here, which is highly inefficient.  You do not need the for loop, and I doubt you need to create a mutable copy of the array at all.

Answer (score 1):

You should remove NSString,NSMutableArray and for loop.. the final code should be like this:

```
NSFileManager *manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSArray *fileList = [manager directoryContentsAtPath:@"/Test"];
cell.textLabel.text = [fileList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
return cell;
```

BTW, this fileList and manager created repeatedly for each cell.. So it is better to make it a global variable for UITableViewController and assign only 1